# how to write ParentListBox.SelectedIndex in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ListBox having ComboBoxes as ListItems. The ComboBox in each ListItem is created using ListBox's ItemTemplate.

Now, suppose I have 5 ListItems. i.e. 5 ComboBoxes.

```
For the 1st ListItem i.e. 1st ComboBox I would like to have all the Items from database as ItemsSource. 
For the 2nd ListItem i.e. 1st ComboBox I would like to have all the Items from database as ItemsSource.
For the 3rd ListItem i.e. 1st ComboBox I would like to have only the selected Items from above Comboboxes as ItemsSource.
For the 4th ListItem i.e. 1st ComboBox I would like to have only the selected Items from above Comboboxes as ItemsSource.
For the 5th ListItem i.e. 1st ComboBox I would like to have only the selected Items from above Comboboxes as ItemsSource.
```

So, I think I have to use different DataSource for different ComboBoxes.

And for that to happen I have the following starting code:

```
<ComboBox....>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="ParentListBox.SelectedIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="DataSource" Value="{Binding Path=ListCorrespondingToValue1}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="ParentListBox.SelectedIndex" Value="Non-0">
                    <Setter Property="DataSource" Value="{Binding Path=ListCorrespondingToValue2}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    <ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Now, my question is what should I use insead of `ParentListBox.SelectedIndex` in the above code and what should I replace Non-0 with?

Comment: I don't know if you can get there from here.  Why not have the selected item on the first box be bound to a property in your ViewModel and in the selected item's property's setter load the next box with an appropriate itemsource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use a `DataTrigger` for the *non zero* part... you just set it as a `Setter` in the `Style`, so that becomes the default value and then the `DataTrigger` changes the `DataSource` property only when the value is `0`. Try this:

```
<ComboBox....>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="DataSource" Value="{Binding 
                Path=ListCorrespondingToValue2}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="ParentListBox.SelectedIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="DataSource" Value="{Binding 
                        Path=ListCorrespondingToValue1}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    <ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: It's not really a trick... it's just setting a property in a `Style.Setter`, but I'm glad it helped.